# AngularJs 1.2.2: Among ngRepeats, by using $interval, ngShow is updated but view is not

Tags: angularjs, intervals, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

Here is a ngRepeat, that repeats **Alerts** for users. I want to show each **alert** one by one in a time period. I am using ngShow and a counter variable **$scope.showedItem**.

**Template**:

```
        <div class="container" >
            <div ng-repeat="headerNotification in headerNotification.list" ng-show="{{showedItem==$index}}">
                    <h3>{{headerNotification.getText()}}</h3>
                    <button ng-click="headerNotification.do()" class="btn btn-warning">{{headerNotification.getButtonText()}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller**:

```
componentHeaderModule.controller('headerController', [
'$rootScope',
'$scope',
'componentHeaderNotification',
'$interval',
function ($rootScope, $scope, componentHeaderNotification, $interval)
{
    ...
    $scope.showedItem = 1;

    $interval(function(){
        $scope.showedItem++;
        if ($scope.showedItem > $scope.headerNotification.list.length)
            $scope.showedItem = 0;
    }, 5000);
}]);
```

When I am looking at *DeveloperTool*, I see that **ng-show** value is changing each 5 seconds, however, *view* is not refreshing, same alert is showing all the time. Even, items class is not changing.

What could be the problem? My understanding of two way binding is a big mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngShow` evaluates an angular expression so you don't want the double curly braces inside it.

So inside:

```
<div ng-repeat="headerNotification in headerNotification.list" ng-show="{{showedItem==$index}}">
```

change this:

```
ng-show="{{showedItem==$index}}"
```

to this:

```
ng-show="showedItem==$index"
```

Angular does not, by default, put a `$watch` on attributes (which helps a lot with performance).  This is why Angular expects you to pass in an expression for it to evaluate.

When you use the double curly braces inside an expression what happens is the expression inside the curlys is evaluated, just once, when the directive is linked in and that result (in your case `true` or `false`) is then passed in and used forever, never changing- even if the attribute's value changes, Angular never notices (since there's no `$watch` on it).

For instance if `showedItem` is equal to 0 when the linking is done, then the first `ngRepeat` entry is passed `true` while every other entry is passed `false`- resulting in what you're seeing, the `ngShow` never changing.

You want the expression to be evaluated every $digest cycle so you pass the expression in.

Comment: I cant believe this! Eventhough ngShow value is changing, it does not affect at all! I need to study harder about it!

Comment: One key is that angular does not put a watch on attributes.  So what happens is the attribute that is passed in at link time is what is evaluated.  Right now you're passing in either `true` or `false`.  Even though the html is changing, it's never re-evaluated.  That's why you want to expression passed in at link.